# Running multiple Java ME Emulators

Tags: eclipse, java-me, sun, java-wireless-toolkit

I am developing an application (a client) that I want to debug by running several instances of it. It communicates with a server which keeps track of all its client.

Now, I want to test the concept by starting several (perhaps three or four) clients at the same time. I am developing using Eclipse Jave ME and Sun WTK as emulator. It would be really simple (I guess) if I could somehow start multiple emulators from the terminal...

How can I do this?